# Как реализовать разные RecyclerView в разных fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Нашёл уйму способов создать `RecyclerView` во фрагменте, но как поместить разные `RecyclerView` в разные фрагменты, так и не могу понять.

Comment: Как вы пробовали это делать и что именно у вас не получилось

Answer (score 1):

При создании фрагмента создается .xml файл и .java.В .xml добавляете RecyclerView, а в .java пишете реализацию его.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?